# Xamarin iOS Refreshing And Maintaining App Using BackgroundTasks

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, background-process, ios13

This is an attempt to use [BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks?language=objc) in Xamarin.iOS.

I have tried to run the sample Application from https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios13/RefreshingAndMaintainingYourAppUsingBackgroundTasks .

Native version (both Swift and Objective C) is working fine.

Platform Details

- Mac OS : `Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6`
- XCode  : `Version 11.1`
- Device : `iPhone 8 Plus | OS 13.1.2`
- Visual Studio : `VS for Mac 8.3.1`

**Expected result** : Periodic updates from the App in the background

**Actual Result**   : No callback triggered. No traces in the console.

---

- Is it possible to create a bindable library from the native swift/objective C code ?
- Hows Xamarin Bindable Library works ?
- Is it really calling the native API (like JNI) or Is it mapping the corresponding Xamarin APIs ?
- Is it possible to create a bindable library without the source code or native library binary ?
- Is it mandatory to wait for a [bug fix](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7456) in the official Xamarin.MaciOS SDK ?

Comment: do you mean you run the sample,it could not wok  ?

Comment: Yes. It didnt work.  :(

Comment: Place an issue in the Github. In the mean time you can use https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny for backgrounding!

Comment: You have just ask something like 10 questions in 1, if there was no bounty that prevents the action I guess this would be closed by users but moderators will probably close it... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's all related. A perfect answer will calrify all these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a Bindable Library for BGTaskScheduler.I did ,

1. Created a iOS Objective C static library containing , enough APIs to register , cancel requests. (Swift is not much supported in Bindable Library projects)
2. Created a fat file for the above library.
3. Created Xamarin.iOS Bindable Library project and referenced the fat file created.
4. Defined the APIDefinitions in the Library and .dll generated.
5. Able to use this .dll file in the Xamarin.iOS project and BGTaskScheduler is working fine.

---

1. Is it possible to create a bindable library from the native swift/objective C code ?

> Yes.[Objective C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos) is preferred for the same

2. Hows Xamarin Bindable Library works ?.

> Bindable library creates a well defined interface between Xamarin.iOS
>   and the 
>        Native APIs.Developer can access the native APIs through this layer.

3. Is it really calling the native API (like JNI) or Is it mapping the corresponding Xamarin APIs ?

> Yes.It is like JNI.When we call the exported method in the
>   APIDefinitions , 
>         its actually calls the Native method.

4. Is it possible to create a bindable library without the source code or native library binary ?

> You need to properly link the required frameworks in the static
>   library.

5. Is it mandatory to wait for a bug fix in the official Xamarin.MaciOS SDK ?

> Not really actually . :)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share the bindings library you created on Github!

Comment: So this BGTaskScheduler will work from iOS version >= 13 only? What about previous versions? Can you let me the way so application data can be refreshed even when the app is killed?